# Redis ExpireAt not working as expected

Tags: redis

As per the Redis docs, EXPIREAT accepts unixtime as the argument specifying the time at which the key gets deleted.

When I execute following commands in redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set bb bb
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> EXISTS bb
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL bb
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIREAT bb 1462173420000 //executed at 1462173300000 ====>>> 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> EXISTS bb //executed after 1462173420000
(integer) 1 =============>>> 2
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL bb
(integer) 1460711246668
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL bb
(integer) 1460711246663
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIREAT bb 100
(integer) 1 ===================>> 3
127.0.0.1:6379> EXISTS bb
(integer) 0 ===================>> 4
```

EXPIREAT executed on bb for time - 2 May, 2016 12:47 PM at 2 May, 2016 12:45 PM.

Even after 2 May, 2016 12:47PM, the key still exits.
Why is this happening?

Why is EXPIREAT accepting invalid unixtime - 100??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXPIREAT` takes values as seconds, not as milli seconds. For millseconds you have to use `PEXPIREAT`. you have given the value as milli seconds so the expire time is set to a higher value.

Small experiment done for your use case:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set karthik 10
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> time //You can use this command to see redis time
1) "1462174316"
2) "692726"
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIREAT karthik 1462174350 //setting the key to expire at 1462174350
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> get karthik 
"10"

127.0.0.1:6379> ttl karthik //use this to see the time left
(integer) 22
127.0.0.1:6379> time
1) "1462174336"
2) "316226"
127.0.0.1:6379> get karthik
"10"
127.0.0.1:6379> time
1) "1462174343"
2) "310511"
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl karthik
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> time //time crossed 1462174350
1) "1462174351"
2) "48589"
127.0.0.1:6379> get karthik //key has got expired
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just found we can use PEXPIREAT. This is same as EXPIREAT but instead takes milliseconds as argument which fits this requirement.

Comment: Why is this working -> EXPIREAT bb 100
(integer) 1 ?? 100 is a unix time 1/1/1970.. why is this expiring the key?

Comment: according to Redis it's just a value, and is less than the current time. And will expire it immediately. In some cases you may want the key to be expired immediately. In those cases you can use a less value to achieve this.